# what's wrong with my simple script?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a very simple script and can't figure out the issue there. the function of the script should be displaying the inner html of each list element but it keeps showing only the last one which is 'Orange'

here is what i have in my html:

```
<ul id='mylist'>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Green</li>
  <li>Black</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

and below is that script:

```
var x = document.getElementById('mylist');
var z = x.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {    
    var res = z[i].innerHTML;
    z[i].setAttribute('onclick','alert(res)');
}
```

I probably need to add a closure here but i am not sure if i really need to and how to add it

Comment: Looks like the UL does not have a closing tag

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('mylist');
var z = x.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        var res = z[i].innerHTML;
        z[i].onclick = function() {
            alert(res)
        };
    })(i);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/UYEa9/

Answer (score 1):

Try this by making res as a identifier instead of string string constant [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBpnv/)

```
var x = document.getElementById('mylist');
var z = x.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(i=0;i<z.length;i++){
      var res = z[i].innerHTML;  
      z[i].setAttribute('onclick',"alert('"+res+"');");

}​
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in another way

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {  
        lis[i].addEventListener('click', 
            function() {
                console.log('asd');
                alert(this.innerHTML);
            }
            , false);
}
```

[Try it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TNjM/)

Using addEventListener is the current recommended way to do this [according to MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution

HTML

```
<ul id="test-list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var x = document.getElementById( 'test-list' );
var li = x.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );

for( var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ) {
    li[i].onclick = function() {
        alert( this.innerHTML );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you have a closing `</ul>` tag:

```
<ul id="test-list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Second, use either the `onclick` property of the DOM object or `addEventListener()`:

```
var x = document.getElementById('mylist');
var z = x.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(i=0;i<z.length;i++){
  z[i].onclick = function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML); // In this scope, "this"
  };                      // means the element that was clicked
}
```

or

```
var x = document.getElementById('mylist');
var z = x.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(i=0;i<z.length;i++){
  z[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML); // In this scope, "this"
  });                      // means the element that was clicked
}
```

If you must use `setAttribute()`, you need to be very careful of scoping. The last value of `res` was `orange`, and that's what the browser remembers. When you click the element, the browser checks the current value of `res` and alerts it. If you use

```
setAttribute('onclick', 'alert"' + res '")');
```

It will take the value of `res` at the current iteration of the `for` loop and inject it into the string.